# Python Dictionary Trouble: Grouping by elements in tuple key

Tags: python, dictionary

so I have a dictionary that looks something like this, with 4 element tuples as keys, and a list of lists as corresponding values. (yay indexing)

```
{('A002', 'R051', '02-00-00', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                                  750],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                                  576],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                                  1486],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                                  595],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                                  841],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                                  1072],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                                  1049]],
 ('A002', 'R051', '02-00-01', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                                  670],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                                  457],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                                  1189],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                                  505],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                                  665],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                                  354],
                                                 [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                                  651]]}
```

I want to modify this dictionary so that I combine values for all keys that have the same 1st, 2nd, and 4th tuple elements. (as the two keys up there do). I would like to combine those two key tuples into one key tuple (so that my combined key is just `('A002', 'R051', 'LEXINGTON AVE')`) and combine the values as well. Is this possible in python?

So, for instance, the first value would be [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 1420] ----- which is 670 + 750, in this case

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wwii - basically the defaultdict methodology that jme nicely summarized below was what I initially used. But then I didn't know how to combine the specific 2nd 'values' in the values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, just go ahead and make another dictionary. Supposing the data you have above is stored in `data`, we'll make a dictionary called `short_data`:

```
short_data = {}
for key, value in data.items():
    short_key = (key[0], key[1], key[3])
    if short_key in short_data:
        short_data[short_key].extend(value)
    else:
        short_data[short_key] = value
```

Or, if you don't mind using a `defaultdict`, you can make this shorter:

```
import collections

short_data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data.items():
    short_key = (key[0], key[1], key[3])
    short_data[short_key].extend(value)
```

If you'd like to combine the values by adding them, I'd suggest using a `Counter`:

```
import collections
short_data = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
for key, value in data.items():
    short_key = (key[0], key[1], key[3])
    short_data[short_key] += collections.Counter(dict(data[key]))
```

Comment: will this combine the 2nd item in each of the values too? For instance, the first value would be [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 1420] ----- 670 + 750 in this case.

Comment: @SpicyClubSauce It will not without modification... I suppose that is what you meant by "combine the values".

Comment: is there a modification that is doable? that's kind of important for me... great solution otherwise.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but the trick is in making it concise and readable. I'll think for a bit.

Comment: would certainly appreciate it - i actually used this same exact defaultdict method myself to make this dictionary initially, but didn't know how to add the specific values in the 'values' together.

Comment: Sure -- For one, it seems like the type of work you're doing would be made easier by the `pandas` library, so you might want to look into that. Secondly, an efficient solution would use a `dict` or even a `collections.Counter` instead of a list to store the `datetime` number pairs. Is that OK. And lastly, are the numbers guaranteed to be integers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82034/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-jme).

Answer (score 2):

Yes , it is very much possible, using `groupby` and `dictionary comprehension` from Python 2.7 onwards.

Example code -

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> import datetime
>>> d = {('A002', 'R051', '02-00-00', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
...                                                   750],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
...                                                   576],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
...                                                   1486],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
...                                                   595],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
...                                                   841],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
...                                                   1072],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
...                                                   1049]],
...  ('A002', 'R051', '02-00-01', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
...                                                   670],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
...                                                   457],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
...                                                   1189],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
...                                                   505],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
...                                                   665],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
...                                                   354],
...                                                  [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
...                                                   651]]}
>>>
>>> newd = {(x[0],x[1],x[2]):[z for a in y for z in a[1]] for x, y in groupby(d.items(),key= lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[0][3]))}
>>> newd
{('A002', 'R051', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 750], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 576], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0), 1486], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0), 595], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0), 841], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0), 1072], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0), 1049], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 670],
[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0), 457], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0), 1189], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0), 505], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0), 665], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0), 354], [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0), 651]]}
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine the 2nd item in each of the values too? For instance, the first value would be [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 1420] ----- 670 + 750 in this case.

Comment: Yes, its possible let me change the script for that

Answer (score 1):

I've added one extra key to your dictionary just to make the solution a little clearer. Here is my input.

```
t = {('A002', 'R051', '02-00-00', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                                      750],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                                      576],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                                      1486],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                                      595],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                                      841],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                                      1072],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                                      1049]],
     ('A002', 'R051', '02-00-01', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                                      670],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                                      457],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                                      1189],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                                      505],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                                      665],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                                      354],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                                      651]],
     ('A002', 'R051', '02-00-01', 'LEXINGTON LANE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                                      670],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                                      457],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                                      1189],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                                      505],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                                      665],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                                      354],
                                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                                      651]]}
```

Now, you can do this.

```
import itertools
groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(t), lambda x:(x[0], x[1], x[3])
```

This will sort the keys of the dictionary and return a list of pairs. The first item in each pair will be the new unique key (the 3 tuple) and the second item will be an iterator that gives you all the original keys that fit into this "group". Now you can "compress" the dictionary like so

```
compressed = {k1:sum((t[k2] for k2 in v),[])
          for k1,v in groups}
```

This basically takes each pair from the groups list. For each pair, it uses the first element as a key (k1) and uses `sum` to combine all the entries in `t` which have keys that map to `k1` into a single list. This is what the `t[k2] for k2 in v`. The `sum` just combines all of these into a single list.

Here is the result.

```
{('A002', 'R051', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                      750],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                      576],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                      1486],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                      595],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                      841],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                      1072],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                      1049],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                      670],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                      457],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                      1189],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                      505],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                      665],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                      354],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                      651]],
 ('A002', 'R051', 'LEXINGTON LANE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                       670],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                       457],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                       1189],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                       505],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                       665],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                       354],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                       651]]}
```

Now, we need to combine the values using the dates. We can write a simple function `combine` like so

```
def combine(l):
    t = itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda v:v[0]), lambda v:v[0])
    return [[k,sum(m[1] for m in v)] for k,v in t]
```

This repeats the above process on a list of 2 tuples. It groups by the first element and then sums the second element for subgroups into a single list.

Finally, to get our final list, you can simply map `combine` to all values of our `compressed` dictionary

```
final = {k:combine(v) for k,v in compressed.iteritems()}
```

Here is the result

```
pprint.pprint(final)

{('A002', 'R051', 'LEXINGTON AVE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                      1420],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                      1033],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                      2675],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                      1100],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                      1506],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                      1426],
                                     [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                      1700]],
 ('A002', 'R051', 'LEXINGTON LANE'): [[datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0),
                                       670],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 21, 0, 0),
                                       457],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 22, 0, 0),
                                       1189],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 23, 0, 0),
                                       505],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 24, 0, 0),
                                       665],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 25, 0, 0),
                                       354],
                                      [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 26, 0, 0),
                                       651]]}
```

Much as I love itertools for being succinct, non trivial expressions usually escape the confines of my limited brain. I often break things down into multiple expressions like this so that it's easier to read, understand and debug.

So, finally, your entire thing can be attained with the following code.

```
def combine(l):
    t = itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda v:v[0]), lambda v:v[0])
    return [[k,sum(m[1] for m in v)] for k,v in t]


groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(t), lambda x:(x[0], x[1], x[3]))
compressed = {k1:sum((t[k2] for k2 in v), [])
              for k1,v in groups}
final = {k:combine(v) for k,v in compressed.iteritems()}
```

From an efficiency standpoint, I don't like this solution. It iterates over the keys and then the values again multiple times. Perhaps you can maintain various elements in more appropriate data structures as you get them. e.g. the list of datetime objects and values could be a `collections.Counter` with keys as the datetimes and values as the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the good long explanation (readable too!) But unfortunately, what I want as my output is for the values to be combined.. not just appended/extended. For instance, the first value would be [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 20, 0, 0), 1420] ----- 670 + 750 in this case. Is that a possible modification?